# Create categorical column in python from string values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, categorical-data

I have a pandas dataframe that includes a "Name" column. Strings in the Name column may contain "Joe", "Bob", or "Joe Bob". I want to add a column for the type of person: just Joe, just Bob, or Both.

I was able to do this by creating boolean columns, turning them into strings, combining the strings, and then replacing the values. It just...didn't feel very elegant! I am new to Python...is there a better way to do this?

My original dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data= [['Joe Biden'],['Bobby Kennedy'],['Joe Bob Briggs']], columns = ['Name'])
```

| 0 | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe Biden |
| 2 | Bobby Kennedy |
| 3 | Joe Bob Briggs |

I added two boolean columns to find names:

```py
df['Joe'] = df.Name.str.contains('Joe')
df['Joe'] = df.Joe.astype('int')

df['Bob'] = df.Name.str.contains('Bob')
df['Bob'] = df.Bob.astype('int')
```

Now my dataframe looks like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data= [['Joe Biden',1,0],['Bobby Kennedy',0,1],['Joe Bob Briggs',1,1]], columns = ['Name','Joe', 'Bob'])
```

| 0 | Name | Joe | Bob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe Biden | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | Bobby Kennedy | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | Joe Bob Briggs | 1 | 1 |

But what I really want is one "Type" column with categorical values: Joe, Bob, or Both.

To do that, I added a column to combine the booleans, then I replaced the values:

`df["Type"] = df["Joe"].astype(str) + df["Bob"].astype(str)`

| 0 | Name | Joe | Bob | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe Biden | 1 | 0 | 10 |
| 2 | Bobby Kennedy | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Joe Bob Briggs | 1 | 1 | 11 |

`df['Type'] = df.Type.astype('str') df['Type'].replace({'11': 'Both', '10': 'Joe','1': 'Bob'}, inplace=True)`

| 0 | Name | Joe | Bob | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe Biden | 1 | 0 | Joe |
| 2 | Bobby Kennedy | 0 | 1 | Bob |
| 3 | Joe Bob Briggs | 1 | 1 | Both |

This feels clunky. Anyone have a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to create the column `Type`.

You need to ordered correctly your `condlist` from the most precise to the widest.

```
df['Type'] = np.select([df['Name'].str.contains('Joe') & df['Name'].str.contains('Bob'),
                        df['Name'].str.contains('Joe'),
                        df['Name'].str.contains('Bob')],
                       choicelist=['Both', 'Joe', 'Bob'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
             Name  Type
0       Joe Biden   Joe
1   Bobby Kennedy   Bob
2  Joe Bob Briggs  Both
```